# Comparing two equal strings but get incorrect result

Tags: java, android, string

So I need to compare my string with string that user inputs in EditText.
I input same string but Java thinks that this is two different strings.
I checked on spaces and didn't find them.

```
private void checkEditTexts(){
    ...
    String userAnswer = editTextAnswer.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
    String rightAnswer = getResources().getString(R.string.question3_answer1).toLowerCase();

    Log.v("checkET.userAnswer", "userAnswer = [" + userAnswer + "] rightAnswer = [" + rightAnswer + "]"  );

    if(userAnswer == rightAnswer) {
        points++;
        Log.v("checkEditTexts()", "POINTS++: " + points);
    }else{
        points--;
        Log.v("checkEditTexts()", "POINTS--: " + points);

    }
    ...
}
```

Logcat:

```
08-29 16:47:27.494 16583-16583/....V/checkET.userAnswer: userAnswer = [song 2] rightAnswer = [song 2]

08-29 16:47:27.494 16583-16583/... V/checkEditTexts(): POINTS--: 2

08-29 16:47:27.494 16583-16583/....V/checkEditTexts(): POINTS--: 1

08-29 16:47:27.494 16583-16583/....V/checkEditTexts(): POINTS: 1
```

You can see that *userAnswer* and *rightAnswer* are equal and it should perform `points++`, but instead it does `points--`

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: @Rotwang It wasn't me. I thankful all of you for helping. I chose as correct answer first one with explanation and upvote other.

Comment: I never suspected **you**. You don't even have enough reputation to downvote.

Comment: @Rotwang "but one": wrong, I downvoted every reputation farming answer. Users with enough reputation and an older account (more than one year old) should already know that they aren't supposed to duplicate answers other and other again. You should know that too.

Comment: @Tom Aren't you way too strict? Just don't upvote the reputation farmers. At maximum, leave them a comment. Downvoting seems a bit too much. And... you forgot **one** answer. Which instead has been UPvoted.

Comment: @Rotwang Maybe yes, maybe no. Imo it ins't helpful to answer the same question over and over again and "not helpful" is a valid DV reason. There are also several meta discussions about that. And I also learned that leaving a comment has a very low chance of being useful. It mostly ends up in arguing, revenge downvotes and "evil community" accuses. There are currently 4 answers (one deleted) and every one has a DV. I "spare" answers of new users, who don't know how this site works. They also get the comment, since the success rate is higher there.

Comment: @Tom Well, if the question is closed (as a duplicate **should be**), then it becomes less visible. If it's also deleted, then it becomes completely invisible to users with less than 10K rep. And about "sparing new users"... that user has a 1300+ rep. I wouldn't consider that one a "new" user.

Comment: @Rotwang *"And about "sparing new users"... that user has a 1300+ rep. I wouldn't consider that one a "new" user. "* As I said, I can't see another answer which hasn't a DV. And the only user with that rep is abbath and his score is 2/1. Maybe the answer you mean has been deleted already? (it should be 6 answers then, since another answer (also with a DV) has been deleted already)

Comment: @Tom OK, I just didn't get into the vote history, my bad.

Comment: @Rotwang No worries. I'm sure it was a caching issue :D.

Comment: @Tom Ehr... Yes, of course. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `equels` or `equalsIgnoreCase`. `==` compare the the reference type not value. but `equels` and `equalsIgnoreCase`  checks for value not reference.

```
if(userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(rightAnswer)) {
points++;
    Log.v("checkEditTexts()", "POINTS++: " + points);
}else{
    points--;
    Log.v("checkEditTexts()", "POINTS--: " + points);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use == when comparing strings.

if(userAnswer.equals(rightAnswer)) { //since you did toLowerCase you can use equals instead of equalsIgnoreCase

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` statements use the `equals` method for String comparison, because in Java, when the `==` operator is used to compare 2 objects, it checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in memory.

Modify your `if` like this:

```
...
if(userAnswer.equals(rightAnswer)) {
   points++;
   Log.v("checkEditTexts()", "POINTS++: " + points);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase (rightAnswer)) {
    points++;
    Log.v("checkEditTexts()", "POINTS++: " + points);
}else{
    points--;
    Log.v("checkEditTexts()", "POINTS--: " + points);

}
```

Comment: why downVote ,Whats the reason

Comment: Someone downvoted all the answers. @Anantham

Comment: yes @KhairulBasarRofi these all answer are perfect way to compare two string,

Comment: Yeah ! Don't understand what's the reason to downvote all the answers. @Anantham

Comment: first answer also same as other answer but that person didn't put downvote for that one@KhairulBasarRofi

Comment: Yeah ! I checked that and edited my comment ! Whoever did this, downvoted all the answers. @Anantham.

Comment: Possibly, a flag to the moderators attention would help.

Comment: It would help to not answer **obvious** duplicates. This is nothing more than lazy reputation farming. Flag the question as duplicate, instead. You have enough reputation to do that. And you're here long enough to know that.

Comment: But, well, **1** not a reason to downvote all indiscriminately - just let it go. **2** one question hasn't been downvoted. And, indeed it has been also UPvoted. Strangely enough.

Comment: @Rotwang As explained above, this wasn't indiscriminately. And the other answer you mean may already has been deleted. I can't see more than these 4. And they all have a DV.

Comment: @Tom So, you can't see the last one (I sort by `oldest`)?

Comment: @Rotwang You mean abbaths answer? It has a DV. The score currently is 2/1. (Too bad others upvote such answers :( ...)